# Entity framework in separate dll

Tags: .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, configuration

I have a class library in which I used entity framework

[image]

I added a unit test project to test the `DAL` dll :

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestConnection()
{
    try
    {
        ICrud<ajt_demande> dem = new Crud<ajt_demande>();
        List<ajt_demande> lst = (List<ajt_demande>)dem.GetAll();
        Console.WriteLine(lst.Count);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        throw new AssertFailedException();
    }
}
```

I get an exception indicates that the connection string is not found !!!

I need to know :

1. What is the reason of this exception?
2. What is the smarter way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection strings are taken from the executing assembly (in your case it's `AjTransport.Test`). Therefore you need to define the connection strings there. There are some options:

1. Pass the connection string directly as part of the constructor (if possible)
2. Add an app.config to your test project defining the connection strings there.